# How to call my file/function name without file extenstion

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I have created a file buy.php in my website root folder and in this file I have created a webservice.

When I am calling API using buy.php/book then it returns the result. Here /buy.php is the file path and book is the function name.

But I want to call this API using buy/book. But it does not give me a result and it shows additionally a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

It was previously running fine but suddenly it stops. Can it be handled by .htaccess?

here is my .htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on 

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# add php if possible
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# rewrite other to index.php file
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert in htaccess, but this works for my api.

```
RewriteRule ^buy/(.*) /buy.php?book=$1 [NC,L]
```

I assumed that "book" was a variable.
So I passed it as a variable to the script.
Is that correct?